# LINQ to Entities - Subquery is coming back in chunks?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have the following LINQ to Entities query, which has a subquery in it. Everything looks fine and it *seems* that the data is coming back as it should be, but it's not. The subquery is actually being chunked somehow. Here's the query:

```
from pg in PhotoGroups
join o in Opportunities
    on pg.OpportunityId equals o.Id
where o.Id == "0067000000hUBRUAA4"
select new {
    CreatedTimestampUtc = pg.CreatedDateUtc,
    DocumentType = pg.DocumentType,
    Items = (
        from p in Photos
        where p.CreatedTimestampUtc == pg.CreatedDateUtc
            && p.DocumentType == pg.DocumentType
            && p.OpportunityId == pg.OpportunityId
        select p.Full
    ),
    OpportunityName = o.Name
}
```

Here's the screenshot from LINQPad:

[image]

The red arrows are where the chunk borders occur. What's weird is that it's being chunked in groups of when the records were being created. What I mean is that I created these records in groups of five, five, five, and four, exactly as they're being chunked.

This chunking ends up causing issues later one when I consume the results in a `foreach` loop. I'm not sure what to do about it, so I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: I doubt it because the column in the database is `date`, so they will always get grouped by the date, and the screenshot above shows they are.

Comment: What do this chunks mean in terms of data and types? This visual image doesn't tell me much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I decided to just live with it because the query result was being projected into the model I wanted, even with the weird chunking. I addressed it at the receiving class's end and adapted to the chunking there.

Answer (score 0):

It's the normal behavior of LINQ - deferred execution.
By default, foreach mechanism will iterate your query 1 item at each loop.
Here, the sub query will be executed in each loop giving back an anonymous type with results for that specific sub query.
If you want it all add ToList/Array of it to be executed as 1 query.

Comment: Tried `ToList` and `ToArray`, but they did nothing and the chunking still continued.

Comment: @Alex - I think the word 'chunks' isn't right and you're mislead by LINQPad view: You requested that each result (outer query) will include a list of results (inner query) - and that's exactly what you see.

Comment: Not quite. The inner query is chunked somehow. I know because the query results were handed off to another class down the pipe. In that class I looped through the inner results and used `IndexOf(item) + 1` to get a temp name which I then used to write the base64 encoded image to an actual file on disk. It was working, but because of the chunking, it was overriding existing files. For example, the bigger inner query had 10 items, but they were chunked into 2x5. When the files were being written to disk, I only saw 1-5, not 1-10.

Comment: Ultimately because I don't have the time to try and correct the query, I accepted it, and in the consuming class I simply incremented a local variable and used that as the file name. I masked the problem, I didn't fix it, but I'm ok with it, for now at least.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to flat your object, so will do all the job with only one query and you can use group by to loop through photos.

```cs
var items = from pg in PhotoGroups
            join o in Opportunities
                on pg.OpportunityId equals o.Id
            join p in Photos 
                on new { p.CreatedTimestampUtc, p.DocumentType, p.OpportunityId } equals new { CreatedTimestampUtc = pg.CreatedDateUtc, pg.DocumentType, pg.OpportunityId }
            where o.Id == "0067000000hUBRUAA4"
            select new {
                CreatedTimestampUtc = pg.CreatedDateUtc,
                pg.DocumentType,
                PhotoFull = p.Full,
                OpportunityName = o.Name
            }.GroupBy(t => new { t.OpportunityName, t.DocumentType, t.CreatedTimestampUtc });


var fetchedItems = items.ToList();
foreach(var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key.OpportunityName);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key.DocumentType);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key.CreatedTimestampUtc);

    foreach(var photo in item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(photo.PhotoFull);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not too worried about the number of SQL queries because this will be used by less than 40 people over the next several months. While this does seem to deliver what I want, I wasn't sure how to project it to the model I wanted it to be in since I had to pass the results to another class and the resultant object structure wasn't not something that I wanted to mess with.